# ACK/NACK Handling Issue In BizTalk 2010 Orchestration - SFTP send port

Tags: biztalk, sftp, biztalk-2010, biztalk-orchestrations

I am using the SFTP adapter and want to get ACK/NACK in the orchestration. I have implemented all the required steps mentioned in the blog [Acknowledgments and Negative Acknowledgments (Part 1)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kevinsmi/archive/2004/07/03/172574.aspx)

I am getting the ACKs, but in case of failure I do not get any NACK. Does anyone know how to get it?

Comment: So the Orchestration port is marked with Delivery Notification = Transmitted, and the Send shape in the Orchestration is in a synchronized scope?    What exception type(s) are you catching in your exception block(s)?  P.S. it is best to document the steps in summary in your question rather than using a link as a link can become outdated and render the question useless to someone else encountering the same issue at a later date.

Comment: I am using the one-way send port, with Binding selected as "Specify later" and Delivery Notification as "Transmitted". The send port's retry has set to zero.

The properties of the Scope shape are: Synchronized = "True" and Transaction Type = "None". The Send shape is inside this Synchronized Scope. After the send shape, I am trying to catch "DeliveryFailureException" in the catch exception shape. 

After applying all these settings, I am still not able to get NACK ( DeliveryFailureException, specifically ) in case of failed scenario. 

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you said you are using NONE for the transaction type? If that is the case I believe that you have to set the Transaction Type of the Scope to "Long Running" for the Delivery of the NACK to occur.