# How to get ACK/NACK in Biztalk orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-orchestrations

Can anyone help me in how to get the ACK/NACK to orchestration once the message is delivered through FILE send adapter. I am using Copy mode = Append in file adapter configuration.

Any specific properties to be used inside orchestration.

Based on ACK/NACK received I have to proceed further in orchestration.

Answer (score 0):

In the logical send port, set the `Delivery Notification = True` also you need to set your Orchestration Transaction Type to Long Running as per [ACK/NACK Handling Issue In BizTalk 2010 Orchestration - SFTP send port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181987/ack-nack-handling-issue-in-biztalk-2010-orchestration-sftp-send-port)